# Enabling a submit button after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am opening up a new page when the user clicks submit.  It would be a common occurrence for the user to come back to the original page to select something else from the drop down and need to "submit" again.  Now the problem is that my js function disables the submit button, and the user would have to reload the page.  The js is a standard thing, so unfortunately, I cant change that, but I was wondering if there was a way to reenable it in HTML or in a separate script, here is my relevant code:

```
<form name="verification_form" action="CreateVerification"   target="_blank" onSubmit="return submitForm(this, 0, this.length-2, SUBMIT)" method="post">
<table width="75%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff<input type="HIDDEN"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">
            <div align="center">
                <select name="stuff" id="stuff" class="R">
                    <option value=" ">   </option>
                    <option value="<% =stuff %>"> <% =stuff %>  </option>
                </select>
        <td><div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"> 
        </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Can you change the onSubmit handler? If so, you could 1) have an ajax call do the actual form submission, 2) re-enable the submit button in the ajax call's complete handler and 3) return false from the replacement onSubmit handler so the default submit behavior did not send the form a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your submit button is disabled. Enable it in that case.

With jQuery this will be the approach:

```
if($("#submit-button").is(":disabled")) {
    $("#submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Not sure what this is doing, I ran it.....and no changes.  I was experimenting with this jquery script, but I cant get it to work either:   *   $('#submit-button').click(function(){  
    $('#submit-button').attr('enabled','true');
  });*

Comment: Oh god, I was thinking that you deleted the button... javascript code changes. Forget last answer, I'm updating it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the disabled option using jquery like this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

The issue would be when exactly in your code do you want to enable the submit button. You will probably want to wire it to the onchange event on your dropdown list.

```
$('#dropdownlist').change(function(){
        //Validate your form here maybe:

        if(validated) $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");                             
  });
```

Comment: Might do this if I cant find a way to do it without the user changing the drop down, thanks.

Comment: If you always want it to be enabled after the page loads (which may not make sense depending on your implementation) you can put it in the document.ready funtion: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");});`

Answer (score 0):

You could put a button somewhere (in the original page or in the popup) that says "select another item" and runs some javascript to re-enable the button with :

```
var submitButton = ... (find the submit button)
submitButton.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wanted to try and avoid putting anything else on the page.

Comment: You can add this script in the popup, then. Use the "opener" variable as a root : opener.getElementById(...) then re-enable it.